# how do I find if any bit of x equals 1 in C

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

Using only bit-wise and logical operations, how can I detect if any bit of x equals to 1 in C? No loops, if/else, ==, or !=

Someone proposed (x & ~0) && 1, but I've been looking at it for hours and still don't know how  (x & ~0) && 1 can detect if any bit of x equals to 1

Comment: `if (x) { /* it is not zero */ }`

Comment: So is your question really "How does (x & ~0) && 1 work?"?

Comment: Note that `x & ~0 == x`, though...

Comment: Do you mean `&& 1` or `& 1`?  The `&& 1` is a pointless no-op.  If you meant `& 1`, it reports on whether the last bit is 1, but you didn't need the `& ~0` either -- unless you're messing with funny sizes of `int` (so `~0` doesn't have as many bits as `x` does).

Comment: I guess my question is two parts. How do i find any bit of x equals to 1 in C using only bit wise, and why, if true,is (x & ~0) && 1 a viable solution

Comment: `(x & ~0) && 1` is a viable solution, but it’s completely pointless, as pointed out above, and equivalent to just `x`, which is your answer. `x`, when treated as a boolean, is true if any of `x`’s bits is one and false otherwise. No other bitwise and/or logical operators necessary. `x | 0`, `~~x`, or `!!x` if it please you.

Comment: @Ry- i checked the value of the expression (x & ~0) && 1 and found that it is not equal or even equivalent to x. The value of the expression is 1, for x != 0. For x = 0, it's 0.

Comment: @tf3: Equivalent to `x` in a boolean context like an `if`. The `& ~0` is completely redundant in any context, though.

Answer (score 4):

`!!x` will do it.

This will convert all values to 1, except for 0 which stays 0. And compilers can optimize this intelligently.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not very familiar with the language of C yet. I konw that ! means not, so doesn't !!x simply returns x? I guess that is the answer that I'm looking for, but for some reason it just sounds a bit weird.

Comment: And what would be the different between !!x and ~~x ?

Comment: `!x` is, in fact, "not x." It turns the value 0 into 1, and all other values into 0.

The second `!` just reverses that, so you're back to where you started, except you always have 0 or 1.

`~x` is a bitwise not. `~~x` just gives you the value you started with exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is a number with all its bits set to 0.

`~` is bitwise NOT - it changes all 0 bits to 1 bits and 1 bits to 0 bits, so `~0` gives a number with all bits set to 1.

`&` is bitwise AND - `&` of two numbers returns a number where each bit corresponds to the logical AND of the corresponding bits in each of the numbers. Since `~0` consists of all 1 bits already, `x & ~0` will simply return a number where each bit corresponds to the same bit in `x`, thus it will return `x`.

See [Wikipedia on bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) (AND and NOT) for more information.

Finally `&&` is a boolean AND operator which will return `1` only if both sides are non-zero. `1` is not zero, thus it simply checks if `(x & ~0)` = `x` (as we established above) is not zero, thus if any of the bits in `x` are 1.

You should notice that there's a lot of redundancy going on here - as already pointed out, you can just use `x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your class assignment?

You wrote "how can I detect ...", but what do you expect for the result of your "detection"?

If the result should be an integer to be fed to `if`/`else`, then you can directly feed the original `x` to `if`/`else`, because C's `if`/`else` can work with any integers and when "any bit of" the input equals 1, the `then` clause will be executed.  Only when the input is exactly `0`, the `else` clause will be executed.  But if your question is your class assignment, this will not be the answer you're looking for.

If you want either `0` or `1` and don't want anything else, use @StilesCrisis's answer.  Because

```
int y = ! x
```

is equivalent to

```
int y;
if (0 == x)
    y = 1;
else
    y = 0;
```

and therefore

```
int z = !! x
```

(whose verbose version is

```
int z = ! ( ! x )
```

) is equivalent to

```
int z;
if (0 == x)
    z = 0;
else
    z = 1;
```

Finally, `(x & ~0) && 1` is as pointless as `x + 0`.